# Does Generic Object match a certain Type?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to determine whether a generic Object matches a certain Type? I have an *ngOnChanges* method where I'd like to perform different actions based on the type of the generic returned.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. Here's the response object:

```
myResponseData = {
    name: 'fu'
    address: '123 ABC Lane'
}
```

Can I determine if this matches either one of these objects?

```
const personModel = {
    name: string;
    address: string;
}

const placeModel = {
    city: string;
    country: string;
}
```

I've tried using a condition like this to match but the response data matches both conditions:

```
if(myResponseData as personModel) {}
else if(myResponseData as placeModel) {}
```

Is there a condition that'll allow me to match a generic against a Type?

Comment: "123 ABC Lane" is a *string* right?

Comment: You'll have to use [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), a runtime check that tells TypeScript something is another type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose two solutions:

**Type predicates**
[type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

[Typescript playground using type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsQFksAmEANsgN4BQy1yIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3FTXAQJQIGDCzYcQPCgF8KFUJFiIUqYivxFSlGsgTAwAT3HsuvXQiwBXcFGOtTU3nIqWQbZMAzoo2PIRJkAF5kAApQAAcrMBY4EEMAShZI6M8MNEwcTUCggD5yPmo3D2EARytgYQJUKCwIsWQAQSgoOEMAHgBrCEMsGAzfLIDifJCAbQAiOkYJgBpkCYEhEQwJgF1zGmEwKygQZDKKqpq6jAA6CAA3aENQiNqI4PyUsDH7urXkAEIgkJsiGCgCAEBLOeTFMBpNQaYbBMIvWLxJKeEBRSFeNDqJDZUh5AoWHAlCDlSrAk71FjNVodbq9frQ7HDUbISb6IxzBaWGzsQzrTbUba7faHUnVB7nK43O4PJ4otFvB6fH5-EAAoEgsGuQmQiKZfYhMi0BjMBboJQcpbCUQsCbYRhgAAWXAmMm4yC17h1WJQBr0BnsEwAMjgCDgOVzbAGAKoAaRdvA92GIEDOxCwnFCAAMAJLpXWDfZwZD5vwsAAkZC8Pj8OLueoSMkzoMTWGTqfTWdzxb1yCLEW95cr3m9tZLOAbTYTEOQnAgIGgwAQ2dRqQNrvkwH64W8etrs-nHCXK7ACQS%20JoAHoL0ZdRgEBwIpCAEYkYCS9IGNK9gY14aFPTar2ghWukIT7guR5omclorPyAGegB3J2HC4GHsuUHTBAYLUEAA)

Sample code

```js
interface PersonModel {
    name: string;
    address: string;
}

interface PlaceModel {
    city: string;
    country: string;
}

const isPersonModel = (input: any): input is PersonModel => {
    const requiredProps: Array<keyof PersonModel> = ["name", "address"];
    return requiredProps.every(prop => input[prop] !== undefined);
}

const isPlaceModel = (input: any): input is PlaceModel => {
    const requiredProps: Array<keyof PlaceModel> = ["city", "country"];
    return requiredProps.every(prop => input[prop] !== undefined);
}

const person = { name: "Peter", address: "something"}; 
const place = { city: "London", country: "UK"};

console.log(`Is person a person: ${isPersonModel(person)}`);
console.log(`Is person a place: ${isPlaceModel(person)}`);

const genericInput = {};

if (isPersonModel(genericInput)) {
    //typescript believes it is a PersonModel
    const address = genericInput.address;
    const country = genericInput.name;
}
```

**Using classes and instanceof operator**

[Playground here for classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdgWRQE3iaA3gFDSnTDoQAuiArsFSogBQAOtARiAJbDRpgAtvABc0aom5oA5gBpo7Lr2hhs2RPChiJU6QEoCAXyLGioSDFjhg8LLnzEy5SjXqMWinn2DcqAT20aXXlPZQpaNBoA8SCZA2NTCjRqaGl4KgB5DgAreAZoAF5oZj0RMDQ-QoA%20QhIybgAzYoARMCp4ADo0FAB3EugAUmgAJkKCooAGPVqnJyTUEE6QFGlmACI0tCQ23QUkVDRoQRw8Nb0AbjrZ6A0qWkRDrZ64ffQ7PHWEdsQ1%20TWAZRo8HS0AAjGdLk5DNA8BB4DNrs5kihFh1lqsNvAtogdjIFNZ4cd7BCrrNbvdHvBnlYwDZ3iB1gAhJA8NC-aBrADiSEE5T8JKhJiIZhcN3K2BQgiyuXyRTSmRyeSoJUuREaxRxaAlUsV%20Sk1HKNhQTRpdJOIGmjjI8xRSxW62lSug3FwkUa3Hg2BUlgJR3NJOM6uYmu1jr1ySohvgxpeyDe5stVxtqPRDt1VGdrqo7s93tjB3pAbqQA)

```js
class PersonModel {
    constructor(public name: string, public address: string){}
}

class PlaceModel {
    constructor(public city: string, public country: string){}
}

const getObject = ():any => {
    if (Date.now() % 2 === 0) {
        console.log("generating person model");
        return new PersonModel("Peter", "Street 1");
    } else {
        console.log("generating place model");
        return new PlaceModel("Berlin", "Germany");
    }
}

const randomObject = getObject();

if (randomObject instanceof PlaceModel) {
    console.log("Object identified as Place model");
}
if (randomObject instanceof PersonModel) {
   console.log("Object identified as PersonModel");
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for such a thorough response. i'm working with interfaces so the first solution worked -- and now i know what a type predicate is.

Comment: Just be aware that my implementation checks only for property existence and not whether the property is of type string for example